# Argument of type "char (*)[16]" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h" 

#define MAXNAME 16

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c, i, j, f;

    char lib[MAXNAME] = "lib\0       ";
    FILE *in, *out;
    char name[MAXNAME];

    /* open input file */
    i = 0;

    while ((name[i] = *argv[1]) != '\0') {
        i++;
        argv[1]++;
    }
    if ((in = fopen(&name, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        goto end;
    }

    /* open output file. Same name as input but with .lib extension */
    while (name[i] != '.') i--;
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (MAXNAME >= (i + j)) {
        name[i + j] = lib[j];
        j++;
    }

    if ((out = fopen(&name, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        goto end;
    }
```

I am trying to open a file in C. I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I compile the previous code I get the following errors.

1. argument of type `char (*)[16]` is incompatible with parameter of
   type `const char *`
2. `FILE *fopen(const char *,const char *)`:
   cannot convert argument 1 from `char (*)[16]` to `const char *`

I understand from the comment that some of my two quantities which I am trying to assign one to the other are in different formats but, I am unable to fix my error. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `fopen(&name, "r")` --> `fopen(name, "r")`

Comment: Or avoid modifying `argv[1]`, and instead simply `fopen(argv[1], "r")`.

Comment: You can take the  file name as argv[1]. "Main" can also be defined as `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])`..

Comment: `name` => pointer to the first char of a char array (`char *`), whereas `&name` => pointer to the whole array of 16 chars (`char (*)[16]`).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a pointer to char name[16], but fopen requires "const char *".

Your solution should be using argv[1] directly in fopen.

```
fopen(argv[1], "r");
```